# How to easiley specify the radius of semicircle(half circle) using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I've written the below code and got the below image.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    


    \draw(0,0)node[draw,shape=semicircle,rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=1cm,fill=green!60]{};
    


    \draw[step=1cm,help lines,dashed](-4,-4)grid(4,4);
    
    \foreach \i in {-4,...,4}{
        \foreach \j in {-4,...,4}{
        \draw(\i,\j)node[below right]{\tiny$(\i,\j)$};
        }
    }
    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to change the radius of the semicircle to 2 in the grid.

Can I achieve it changing little bit of the above code?

Specifying "radius=2" didn't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it drawing an arc.

```
\draw[fill=green!60] (0,2) arc (90:270:2) -- cycle;
```

With this we are drawing an arc starting at the point (0,2) with an initial angle 90, ending angle 270 and radius 2.

Changing your code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} % <-- noth needed

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[fill=green!60] (0,2) arc (90:270:2) -- cycle;

    \draw[step=1cm,help lines,dashed](-4,-4)grid(4,4);
    
    \foreach \i in {-4,...,4}{
        \foreach \j in {-4,...,4}{
        \draw(\i,\j)node[below right]{\tiny$(\i,\j)$};
        }
    }
    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The arc solution is OK, obviously. But if you still want to use a semicircle shaped node, you can do it, but you have to set it up with `inner sep=0pt` and `minimum height=2cm`.

[image: semicircle node]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    


    \draw(0,0)node[draw,shape=semicircle,rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt, minimum height=2cm,fill=green!60]{};
    


    \draw[step=1cm,help lines,dashed](-4,-4)grid(4,4);
    
    \foreach \i in {-4,...,4}{
        \foreach \j in {-4,...,4}{
        \draw(\i,\j)node[below right]{\tiny $(\i,\j)$};
        }
    }
    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```